# A word for the feeling of not being able to stand the smell of alcohol

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word for the feeling someone may have who recently had a blackout or was so hungover that they can't even stand smelling something alcoholic?

You know what I mean; the feeling that makes you throw up if you smell or drink an alcoholic beverage.

Something like alcoholo-phobic?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a word specifically relating to the smell of alcohol.  Are you after a word to describe the person, or a word to describe the feeling?

Comment: The "Feeling" actually.

Comment: I don't think such word exists, to be honest. You're just hungover, and the smell of alcohol is repulsive to you due to your condition. It's hard to combine "repulsion towards the smell of alcohol" into one word :)

Comment: Not exactly but that's good for another line of my text. Thanks @Susan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a word specifically related to alcohol but I may suggest:

***"[Repulsion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repulsion?q=repulsion)"***

> *noun*
>   [*mass noun*]
>     1a feeling of intense distaste or disgust:
>       *people talk about the case with a mixture of fascination and repulsion*

Although, actually, on further reading:

***"[Alcoholophobia](http://www.drugs.com/dict/alcoholophobia.html)"*** does appear to be recognised:

> Definition: Morbid fear of alcohol, or of becoming an alcoholic.

Comment: This is great thanks. Actually "Alcoholophobia" is a long-term feeling toward drinking but I'm looking for that temporary period of time in which you can't drink anything.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if I don't get any better. Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: No problem.  I'll have a think to see if I can muster up some alternatives.  You could use "short-term alcoholophobia", I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **[revulsion](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revulsion)**

> a sudden and unpleasant violent reaction in feeling, esp one of extreme loathing

Answer (score 2):

The medical term is ***nausea***. *A feeling of sickness with an inclination to vomit*

Nausea in the midst of a hangover strikes whenever you smell, taste, or even *look at* anything remotely related to food and beverages. A person hungover might say: *I can't bear the sight of anything to eat or drink. I just feel too nauseous*

[wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-a-Hangover) says this:

> One of the main causes of nausea during a hangover is not just because
>   of the alcohol itself (myth), a good portion of it is the low blood
>   sugar ( liver using up all available glucose to process the alcohol)
>   and the increased stomach acid production ( especially if you drank
>   red wine).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangover#Signs_and_symptoms) states

> An alcohol hangover is associated with a variety of symptoms that may
>   include drowsiness, concentration problems, dry mouth, dizziness,
>   gastrointestinal complaints, fatigue, sweating, **nausea**,
>   hyper-excitability, anxiety and a feeling of general discomfort